# Angular doesn't display the correct text for options in a drop down

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Has anybody else had to support Angular back to IE7 before? I’ve got an issue in both 8 and 7 when creating a drop down list.

```
<select data-ng-model="relatedProduct.quantity" data-ng-init="setSelect(relatedProduct)">
    <option data-ng-repeat="i in getNumber(relatedProduct.maxQuantity) track by $index" value="{{ $index }}">{{ $index }}</option>
</select>
```

Ignore the `ng-model` and `ng-init` on the `select`. `getNumber()` is a function that will return an array from 1 to a given max value, and therefore the max number of options that will be rendered.

The problem I have is that when I open the drop down the text of each of the options is `{{ $index }}`. The value attributes of the options are correct, as whenever I choose a new one, the correct value is displayed. The issue is only when the drop down is open.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using ngOptions instead?

Comment: "when I open the drop down the text of each of the options is {{ $index }}." -- What else did you expect it to be?

Comment: @Blazemonger I would have expected the text to be a number representing the position in the array. 1, 2, 3, etc. This works for the `value` attributes but not the actual element text.

Comment: @AnthonyChu Yeah we tried that too. But instead of {{ $index }} the options are just empty.

Comment: @ashrobbins $index is not available in ngOptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `select`s, you should be using `ngOptions` instead of `ngRepeat`. `$index` is not available in `ngOptions`, so you can just use `i`...

```
<select data-ng-model="relatedProduct.quantity"
    data-ng-options="i for i in getNumber(relatedProduct.maxQuantity)"></option>
</select>
```

If `getNumber()` returns an array from 1 to max, this won't quite produce the same result as using `$index` (`$index` is 0-based). If you need the dropdown to start from 0, you can do this...

```
<select data-ng-model="relatedProduct.quantity"
    data-ng-options="(i - 1) as (i - 1) for i in getNumber(relatedProduct.maxQuantity)"></option>
</select>
```

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7fkeagwm/). Unfortunately I don't have a copy of IE 7 to test with but it should work.

Comment: This works really well. Thanks so much, I've been pulling my hair out on this. @Anthony Chu

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of issues with the select tag and angular. The best fix I've found is to create the options array in your controller first and then use ng-options attr.

```
mainApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.quantities = [
        {text : '0', value : 0},
        {text : '1', value : 1},
        {text : '2', value : 2},
    ];
    $scope.selectedQuantity = $scope.quantities[0];

});

<select ng-model="selectedQuantity" ng-options="item.text for item in quantities"></select>
```